# Rejecting and then Resolving a Q Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I have seen code that looks like this:

```
var defer = Q.defer();
// do something, here's the callback
if (err) {
   defer.reject({err: err})
}
defer.resolve({success: data});
// close callback
return defer.promise;
```

If a promise is first rejected, and then resolved, it appears that the "rejection" remains.

When I first saw this pattern, I was inclined to suggest to wrap the resolve inside an `else`, but since it works as is, is this an acceptable pattern?

Could there ever be a problem with rejecting and then resolving a promise?

It appears that if you resolve and then reject, the resolution remains. So whichever happens first, is what "sticks"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So whichever happens first, is what "sticks"?

Yes, exactly. The state of a promise is immutable once it is settled (either fullfilled or rejected). So no, there can't be a problem occurring here, the promise is "locked" as rejected if the rejection happens first.

However, think about if a single else doesn't actually improve your code quality. Less code lines don't necessarily improve code readability! I'd say it would, because it's much easier to quickly understand what happens if you see an if/else. What if someone else has to look at your code, and they also at first don't know that promises are immutable after settling?

[Chapter 3 of "You Don't Know JS (async & performance)"](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20&%20performance/ch3.md) is an excellent resource to more fully grasp promises. And so is the [Promises A+ specification](https://promisesaplus.com/), which Q conforms to. The latter is more of an "objective source of truth", but it's harder to read (well, it's a spec).